# php mail() function and IIS

Tags: php, .net, iis

I have coded a site with PHP. Our client deployed the site to IIS. They installed PHP 5.2 but `mail()` function doesnt work on their server.

They added this config file in the www folder:

`web.config:`

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="PHP- fastcgi" />
            <add name="PHP - FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="*" 
                 modules="FastCgiModule" 
                 scriptProcessor="C:\Php\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="default.php" />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The following error is generated by the `mail()` function:

```
server error - 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

I know there must be a simple solution with an edit of the `php.ini` file. But the person in charge has said that they couldnt edit `php.ini` and we have to code contact page with asp.

Is there any way to send mail using php in this case?

Comment: Can you describe what about `mail` isn't actually working?  How about the code you're using to call it.

Comment: server eroor - 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: please check the error log for the site.  Check the `log_errors` and `error_log` directives in php.ini for more information on where to find the actual log file.  If `log_errors` is "Off" or `error_log` is blank, correct that problem and try again.  Also, again, please post the PHP code you are using that is failing.

Comment: What version of IIS? Do you have an SMTP server set up already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a long outstanding bug in the `mail()` function in PHP 5.2 on Windows:

> [Bug #28038 Sent incorrect RCPT TO commands to SMTP server](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=28038)

The `From:` header was being parsed incorrectly by the `mail()` function and most properly behaved RFC compliant mail servers will reject it as an invalid address.

This is now fixed in PHP 5.2.11+ (I have tested this with PHP 5.2.14, PHP 5.2.17 and PHP 5.3.6). So I'd find out the exact version of PHP 5.2.x your application is running under and see if it's affected by this bug.

However, I'd recommend using [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) instead. You get a lot more control over stuff like configuring the outgoing mail server, authentication and so on and it doesn't rely on using the built-in `mail()` function. We have several customers using this on our shared hosting platform and they're very happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try and set options with

> ini_set()

function

[ini_set reference](http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: with : ini_set("SMTP","localhost");  
 ini_set("smtp_port","25");
 ini_set("sendmail_from","string"); but result is the same